# Flutter Sembast insert or update

Tags: flutter, dart

How to implement insert if no records with the id else update with `sembast` library in flutter?
I tried the below.

```
Future updateOrInsert(User user) async {
    final result = await update(user);
    if(result == 0){
      insert(user);
    }
 }

 Future update(User user) async {
    final finder = Finder(filter: Filter.byKey(user.id));
    final result = await _userStore.update(await _db, user.toMap(), finder: finder);
    return result;
 }

 Future insert(User user) async {
    await _userStore.add(await _db, user.toMap());
 }
```

It's working fine. Is this the right solution or is there any other direct sembast APIs available?

[sembast](https://pub.dev/packages/sembast)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `Record.put` to either add or update a record with a given id.

```dart
Future updateOrInsert(User user) async {
  await _userStore.record(user.id).put(_db, user.toMap());
}
```

Comment: I'm using quite a complex solution to solve this exact problem as I use `.add` but I see that using `.put` would simplify it quite a lot.  What's the difference using `.add`vs `.put`? Thanks

Comment: `.put` will create the record if it does not exist. `.add` will fail if the record already exists

Comment: sure.. is NoSql..same as in firebase. Thanks

Comment: does `put` replace the whole existing record ?

Comment: record(int key) requires an integer,, while all my model's IDs are simply strings ,, this means I should search for them and check if they do not exist to add them,, 
I can't transform all my models IDs to integers !!

Am I missing something ?